# Write a function that randomly draws five cards from the deck in R (full explanation)

Tags: r, function

***"Please create a deck of cards and store the face, suit and value information in a data frame. Write a function that randomly draws five cards from the deck."***

This is my code for the data frame

```
    suit<-c("clubs","diamonds", "hearts", "spades")
    face<-c("king", "queen", "jack", "ten", "nine", "eight", "seven", "six", "five", "four", "three", "two", "ace")
    num<-c(13, 12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
    deck <-data.frame(face=rep(face,4),
                      suit=c(rep("spades", 13), rep("clubs", 13), rep("diamonds", 13), rep("hearts", 13)),
                      num=rep(num,4))
```

This is code @Ronak came up with

```
    draw_n_random_cards <- function(deck, n) {
  deck[sample(nrow(deck), n), ]
}

set.seed(123)
result <- draw_n_random_cards(deck, 5)
result
```

Is my understanding of this code correct?

**1. Created  a function called “draw_n_random_cards with arguments “deck” and “n.”

****2. The code for the function uses notation [sample(nrow(deck), n,] to work within the deck for drawing random cards. “Nrow” returns the number of rows in data frame “deck” and “n” as the size of the same. “Nrow” returns the 52 rows of the deck and “n” will draw cards from the 52 rows.**

**3. Set.seed() function allows the same sample to be reproduced each time and get the same results for the same seed number (123).**

**#4. “Result” is going to run the random sample for 5 cards. Is this the correct logic?**

My last question is: even if I run the “result” object w/o the seed(123) function, the 5 cards are the same on the output (face, suit, number are the same). How would I generate a new set of 5 random cards, if I choose too?

Comment: There are many problems in your loop code.  `i in suits`, `j in cards` will not give numerical values as you are using `i, j` for sub-setting through `[]`.  Moreover, I cannot understand the reason for this while loop.

Comment: I’m not sure what the reasoning was, it wasn’t my code. It was someone’s else’s code for drawing 5 random cards and return 5 numerical vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sample` to select `n` random cards.

```
draw_n_random_cards <- function(deck, n) {
  deck[sample(nrow(deck), n), ]
}

set.seed(123)
result <- draw_n_random_cards(deck, 5)
result

#    face     suit num
#31  nine diamonds   9
#15 queen    clubs  12
#14  king    clubs  13
#3   jack   spades  11
#42  jack   hearts  11
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to follow the logic to make sure I understand correctly. 

1. You created a function called “draw_n_random_cards with arguments “deck” and “n.” 

2. The code for the function uses notation [sample(nrow(deck), n,] to work within the deck for drawing random cards. “Nrow” returns the number of rows in data frame “deck” and “n” as the size of the same.

Comment: “Nrow” returns the 52 rows of the deck and “n” will draw cards from the 52 rows. 3. Set.seed() function allows the same sample to be reproduced each time and get the same results for the same seed number (123). #4. “Result” is going to run the random sample for 5 cards. Is this the correct logic?

Comment: My last question is: even if I run the “result” object 5 cards are the same on the output (face, suit, number are the same).

Comment: Yes, you have got it correct. `result` is just a variable used to store the random cards. If you want different card each time you run `draw_n_random_cards`. Remove `set.seed` from the code.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sample_n` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
deck %>%
   sample_n(5)
```